# WEEKOFYEAR 3 weeks ago

Tags: mysql

I am looking to be able to run a simple query to show the week of the year for 3 weeks ago. I have tried the following without luck.

```
select WEEKOFYEAR(CURDATE()) - INTERVAL  3  WEEK
```

Comment: `WEEKOFYEAR` returns an integer value – trying to subtract a date interval from that makes no sense. The only thing that makes sense is of course to do it the other way around – subtract three weeks from the current date, and then apply `WEEKOFYEAR` to the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MySQL native function for computing the date differences:

```
 select WEEKOFYEAR(DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 3 WEEK))
```

Comment: Thats the ticket. Cheers!

Comment: What you had initially would have worked as well – if you only had set the round brackets correctly.

Comment: @CBroe Yup, got it to work just for my fun. Thanks for the info.